# Upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 on HP Elitebook 840 G1 results in blinking cursor after bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, hp, 19.04

I used to dual boot Windows (on `dev/sda1`) and Ubuntu 18.04, on my HP Elitebook 840 G1 (SSD).
I also have a third partition for most of my files (I believe on `dev/sda2` named D:/).

I tried upgrading to 18.10, which worked, after which I wanted to upgrade to 19.04.
GRUB still finds the boot options I want, but when I try to boot into Ubuntu, I get a blinking cursor (after the ubuntu logo). Also going into "advanced options" in GRUB and selection 4.15.0-55-generic gives me the blinking cursor (after the ubuntu logo).

I wanted to know if anyone had managed to solve this? I have tried:

- booting from a stick with Ubuntu 19.04 (most of the times it doesn't even boot into the stick, and when it does, I also get a flashing underscores)
- boot into recovery mode and change the GPU settings as proposed by heynnema ([gdm3 display manager hangs after booting with Ubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107042/gdm3-display-manager-hangs-after-booting-with-ubuntu-18-10))

The fact that even booting from stick gives an error maybe indicates that it indeed is a graphic error?

Comment: How is this question not properly formulated? I believe something must be wrong, as I got a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper answer, but I didn't get anywhere. What I tried and failed:

- reinstall GRUB
- reinstall graphics card

I ended up switching back to Ubuntu 18.04 (reinstalled 18.04 from stick onto the partition of the "broken" 19.04). Now I have a GUI. Will wait for 20.04.